# Sorting variables in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @user;
my $count = 0;
my @test;
my @last = qx(last);
my @logins;

# Opens the file /etc/passwd and puts the users with an uid
# over 1000 but less that 65000 into an array.
open( my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd") or die "/etc/passwd failed to open.\n";

while (my $lines = <$passwd>) {
    my @splitarray = split(/\:/, $lines );

    if( $splitarray[2] >= 1000 && $splitarray[2] < 65000) {
        $user[$count] = $splitarray[0];
        #print "$user[$count]\n";
        $count++;
    }
}
close $passwd;

for my $i (0 .. $#user) {
    my $counter = 0;
    @logins =qx(last $user[$i]);
    for my $j (0 .. $#logins) {
        if ($logins[$j] =~ /$user[$i]/) {
            $counter++;
        }
    }

    print $user[$i] . ":" . $counter . "\n";
}
```

And the output from this looks like this:

```
user1:15
user2:3
user3:6
user4:2
```

How can i sort this so that it shows the users with the most logins at the top? I tried with a hash but couldn't seem to get it right. Since they are not arrays i don't know how to sort them.

Comment: Instead of reading /etc/passwd have you looked into using the built-in `getpwent` function?  It may prove to be a little more PAM friendly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one login counter. In order to sort the users by login count, you will need each user's login count.

```
my %logins_by_user;
for my $user (@users) {
   $logins_by_user{$user} = grep /^\Q$user\E /, `last '$user'`;
}

for my $user (
   sort { $logins_by_user{$b} <=> $logins_by_user{$a}  ||  $a cmp $b } @users
) {
    print("$user: $logins_by_user{$user}\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version which uses a hash and prints the users sorted by login count:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

open(my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd") or die "/etc/passwd failed to open.\n";

my %login_count;
while (<$passwd>) {
  my @splitarray = split(/\:/);
  if ($splitarray[2] >= 1000 && $splitarray[2] < 65000) {
    my $user   = $splitarray[0];
    my @logins = qx(last $user);

    # Remove lines that don't mention the user name
    @logins = grep /$user/, @logins;

    # Using an array in scalar context returns the number of items in the array
    $login_count{$user} = @logins;
  }
}
close $passwd;

# List users sorted by login count
say "$_ : $login_count{$_}"
  for sort { $login_count{$a} cmp $login_count{$b} } keys %login_count;
```

Comment: `grep` in scalar context returns the number of matches. No need for that wasteful array. /// That regex is really poor. If my user name was my initials (`eb`), the count would be off by one when `wtmp` begins in February. /// You really should handle the order of users with the same login count better than that!

Comment: The wasteful array is deliberate, to make it more clear to the OP what's going on. The rest... well... I seem to have been having an off day.

Comment: Again, could have made it a scalar (`my $num_logins = `) to get the same effect.